# Render to winforms picturebox over and over again

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have some bugs that need fixing, one of them involves an out of memory error.
Does anyone know how to do this properly? Thanks, I don't want it to be too messy, or too complicated. I just want to treat a new image as a buffer to render another image to (because of positional changes), and do it via a background thread. Not the UI thread (Too slow likely). 
I get out of memory errors, and such. Also not able to access members of Form1 from within the thread function (images and the like throw access errors such as "Object already in use")

Here is my code:

```
System.Threading.Thread t;
public Image b;
public Bitmap c;
public Bitmap d;
public Bitmap e;
public Bitmap bg;
public Bitmap spr;
int spritex = 0;
int spritey = 0;
int spritedir = 1;

public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Text = "Escape The Hypno Mansion!!".ToString();

    t = new System.Threading.Thread(DoThisAllTheTime);
    t.Start();
    textBox1.Text = "Press Begin button to start!";
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Images\introgirl.jpg");
    b = new Bitmap(@"Images\introgirl.jpg");
    c = new Bitmap(@"Images\sprite.png");
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);

    Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    graphics.DrawImage(c, new Point(500, 500));
    pictureBox1.Image = b;

    //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}

public void DoThisAllTheTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Point p = new Point(spritex, spritey);
        bg = new Bitmap(@"Images\test.bmp");
        spr = new Bitmap(@"Images\sprite.png");

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bg))
        {

            graphics.DrawImage(spr, p);
        }
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {

            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bg;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        if (spritedir == 1) { spritex += 5; }
        if (spritedir == 2) { spritex -= 5; }

        if (spritex < 0) { spritex = 0; spritedir = 1; }
        if (spritex > 700) { spritex = 700; spritedir = 2; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I should mention the reason I keep declaring new is because if I try to load the images once on the forms main thread and keep them there, I get errors such as "object already in use" and I'm not able to actually access it in the background thread...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [your question is just a rant in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I edited my post to try to be more clear on the issue. Please support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't change the image in your picturebox is because the thread that created the image is not the thread that created the picturebox.

In a debugger you can check this by asking the picturebox for InvokeRequired (function [Control.IsInvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) just before changing the function.

So let's rewrite your function and show that modern classes Like Task are much easier to use the your thread.

I'll start your task when the form is loading, and try to stop it when the form is closing.

```
private Task myTask = null;
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void OnFormLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Start the task
     this.myTask = Task.Run( () => DoMyWork(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token));
}

private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // if the Task is still running, ask it to stop itself:
    if (myTask != null && !myTask.IsCompleted)
    {   // ask the task to stop and wait until it is completed:
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        // all Tokens extractes from this source will get state CancellationRequested

        // wait maximum 5 seconds until the task is completed:
        this.UseWaitCursor = true;
        this.myTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        this.UseWaitCursor = false;            

        //  cancel closing if the task is still not completed
        e.Cancel = !this.myTask.Completed;
    }
}
```

Now the function DoMyWork:

```
private void DoMyWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Do the same as in your DoThisAllTheTime
    // except that you regularly check cancellationToken.IsCancelRequested:
    while(!cancellationToken.IsCancelRequested)
    {
        // calculate the image to display
        var imageToDisplay = ...
        this.DisplayImage(imageToDisplay);
    }
}

void DisplayImage(Image imageToDisplay)
{
    if (this.pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => this.DisplayImage(imageToDisplay)));
    }
    else
    {
        this.PictureBox1.Image = imageToDisplay;
    }
}
```

See:

- [How to cancel a Task and its children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)
- [Use InvokeRequired with lambda expression](https://mutelight.org/using-the-invoke-design-pattern-with-anonymous-methods)

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try this solution soon.

Comment: There are some issues with it. I tried to implement it and it isn't displaying any moving image over the picturebox image which is what should happen. Where'd I go wrong? [source:](https://pastebin.com/akQEargM)
Here is what I should be seeing or something like it: [gif file](https://i.gyazo.com/484338a17a510f1595b9476f4b7c2230.gif)

Comment: To debug your problem. Put your image creation procedure in a smaller project where you display the next created image in aPictureBox after a button is clicked. This way you are certain that your image creation procedure works correctly. Now do the same with the Image Display Function: create two images, and let it display first one, wait a second, then the other image wait a second etc. Then combine the two

Answer (score 1):

Dispose every disposable instances before the loop ends. Your memory leak is related with disposable items not being cleaned from memory, so you'll eventually run out of memory in your infinite loop.

At the very least, you'll want to dispose both bitmaps at the end of the loop:

```
    bg = new Bitmap(@"Images\test.bmp");
    spr = new Bitmap(@"Images\sprite.png");
```

Comment: This answer is valid thank you but I'm going to give the winning answer to Harald